# Elasticsearch escape slash

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7 and I am trying to build up a search request in this way:

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "document": {
                "value": "/home/myfolder"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

in order to find all folders starting with /home/myfolder ("document" element is stored like a path "/home/myfolder/file.txt". I am trying many ways but I didn't found any way to escape properly "/" character. In other links, people suggested to use "\/home/myfolder" or "/home/myfolder" but it does not work.

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to match with the `/` use `.keyword` as below.

```
 {
        "query": {
            "prefix": {
                "document.keyword": {
                    "value": "/home/myfolder"

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is because when you dont use keyword, you are trying to match against an analyzed field and by default it removes the `/`.

Try running this and see how it breaks at each slash (`/`) to create the inverted index.

```
POST /_analyze
{

  "text" :"/home/myfolder/document.txt"
}
```